# press and drag eraser for a uiimageview in swift2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift2, core-graphics

I am just starting on iOS graphics (core graphics) and am trying to implement a 'paint like' **eraser**. I want to erase parts of my image or just make certain parts transparent so that the view underneath can be seen wherever my finger has dragged across. I ran across **quartz 2D** but i am unsure on how I could use this to erase from an imageview.

I already handled all of the touch events (touching and dragging) but I do not know how I would implement the part that makes the layer transparent.

i see `CGContextDrawImage` but am unsure on how to use it or if that is the right thing all together.

much apreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set blend mode to .Clear before you stroke:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), .Clear)
```